# Xpath is correct but Scrapy spider doesn't work

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to download from a webpage, I identify the XPath expression and then run the spider, but nothing is downloaded.
The webpage: https://octopart.com/electronic-parts/integrated-circuits-ics
Here is the code:

```
for product in response.xpath("//div[@class='serp-card-header media']/div[@class='media-body']"):
        yield {'name': product.xpath("//a/span[@class='part-card-manufacturer']/text()").extract_first()}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website seems to be using some simple bot detection. You are most likely using the default scrapy user agent. So instead you need to set a real user agent in your `settings.py`:

```
USER_AGENT = '[replace with a real user agent]'
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent).

After doing this you will get some results. However, your XPath is incorrect as well. Inside the for loop, when you do a relative XPath, it needs to start with `.//a/span...`. See here for the reason why: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths

Comment: Which user agent do you suggest for this purpose?

Comment: @Joanna Any of the top ones here (excluding the obvious bots): http://www.browser-info.net/useragents